# преобразовать аргумент из "System::String ^" в "std::string"

Tags: c++-cli

Нужна помощь с преобразованием строки для последующего чтения и вычисления хеш-суммы файла.

Ошибка на 54 строке.
Как мне преобразовать тип файла или написать перечисление файлов в каталоге на нативном C++

Ошибка  C2664   "std::string sha224(std::string)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "System::String ^" в "std::string"

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>
#include "sha224.h"

  using namespace System;
  using namespace System::IO;

 using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::string;

 int main()
{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
//Составление списка каталогов и файлов
String^ path = "C:\\tasm";
DirectoryInfo^ di = gcnew DirectoryInfo(path);
array<FileInfo^>^fiArr = di->GetFiles();
Console::WriteLine("--== Файлы внутри '{0}' ==--", di->Name); cout << endl;

System::Collections::IEnumerator^ myEnum = fiArr->GetEnumerator();

while (myEnum->MoveNext())
{

    FileInfo^ f = safe_cast<FileInfo^>(myEnum->Current);
    FileInfo^ fi1 = gcnew FileInfo(path);
    // Имя файла
    cout << "........................................." << endl;
    cout << "Имя файла: ";
    Console::WriteLine(f->Name);
    cout << "" << endl;

    // Размер файла
    printf("Размер файла: ");
    Console::WriteLine("{1} Байт.", f->Name, f->Length);
    cout << "" << endl;

    // Путь к файлу
    cout << "Путь к файлу: ";
    Console::WriteLine(f->FullName);
    cout << "" << endl;
    using namespace std;

    //Вычисление хеш-функции
    cout << "Хеш-сумма файла: " << sha224(f->FullName) << endl;


    //cout << "" << endl;



}



system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в винде, но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы передаёте указатель, а нужно ссылку. Попробуйте добавить звёздочку перед FullName : `sha224(*(f->FullName))`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Проблема глубже, FullName - строка из С++/CLI, а библиотека ожидает строку из стандартного С++

Comment: Возможно ли передать строку из CLI в виде стандартного C++?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, при добавлении звездочки появляется ошибка - "
Ошибка (активно) E0312 не существует подходящего определяемого пользователем преобразования из "System::String" в "std::string""

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте переписал код полностью. Из C++/CLI используется только перебор файлов - это несложно сделать на нативном C++. Или, наоборот, все сделать на управляемой версии языка. Вам действительно нужен именно sha224? Не устроит sha256/384/512? Их реализации в неймспейсе [System.Security.Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Подходит любой тип шифрования, будь то MD5,MD4 или какой-либо Sha. Просто близок дедлайн , а это единственный способ перебор файлов, который я нашел. Перебор на чистом Си я вообще не смог найти

Comment: Маршаллинг не помог?
`sha224(static_cast<char*>(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(f->FullName).ToPointer()))`.
И не забыть добавить ссылку на пространство имён: System.Runtime.InteropServices

Comment: Действительно, для перечисления файлов в каталоге вообще не нужен .NET. Используйте std::filesystem из нового стандарта: https://stackoverflow.com/a/612176/8674428 (А MD5 - не шифрование, а хэш-функция, если на то пошло)

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему переписав полностью код. Теперь выполняет свою задачу

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sha224.h"
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
using namespace::std;

int main()

{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

//Директория в которой находятся файлы
string path = "C:/tasm";        

//Вывод заголовка
cout << "                        Файлы в каталоге " << path << endl; cout << endl;

//Цикл вывода файлов
for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
{
    std::experimental::filesystem::path p(p);

    // Имя файла
    cout << "...................................." << endl;
    std::cout << "Имя файла: " << p.stem() << std::endl;              

    // Путь к файлу
    cout << "Путь к файлу: " << p << endl;

    // Вычисление размера файла
    cout << "Размер файла: " << fs::file_size(p) << " Байт" << endl;

    // Вычисление хеш-суммы
    ifstream file(p);
    string s;
    while (file)
    {
        file >> s;
    }
    cout << "Хеш-сумма файла: " << sha224(s) << endl;


}
system("pause");
}
```